# How to get in Asp.Net Core a request POST from Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, filter

**In Asp.NET MVC I was using Filters according below: (It works fine)**

```
public class TracerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueAddress"];
            var queue = new MessageQueue(path);
            queue.DefaultPropertiesToSend.Recoverable = true;

            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var body = TraceMessageHelper.BuildBody(actionContext, assembly);
            try
            {
                var label = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MessageLabel"] + body.Timestamp.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                var message = new Message
                {
                    Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(TraceMessage) }),
                    Label = label,
                    Body = body
                };

                queue.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("LogInFile");
                logger.Warn(e, LogMessageHelper.FormatRequest("TRACE SEND FAILED", actionContext.Request));
                if (body != null)
                {
                    var tracerlogger = LogManager.GetLogger("TracerInFile");
                    tracerlogger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));
                }
            }

            queue.Close();
        });
    }
}
```

}

**In Asp.NET CORE I'm using Filters according below: (It doesn't Work)**

```
public class TracerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {            

        {
            var path = "FormatName:Direct=TCP:013cdnt2305\\private$\\TracerQueue";

            var queue = new MessageQueue(path);
            queue.DefaultPropertiesToSend.Recoverable = true;

            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var body = TraceMessageHelper.BuildBody(actionContext, assembly);
            try
            {

                var label = "APR_USER_20191018132324";
                var message = new Message
                {
                    Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(TraceMessage) }),
                    Label = label,
                    Body = body
                };

                queue.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpRequestMessageFeature hreqmf = new HttpRequestMessageFeature(actionContext.HttpContext);

                var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("LogInFile");


                logger.Warn(e, LogMessageHelper.FormatRequest("TRACE SEND FAILED", hreqmf.HttpRequestMessage));
                if (body != null)
                {
                    var tracerlogger = LogManager.GetLogger("TracerInFile");
                    tracerlogger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));
                }
            }

            queue.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**In ASP.net Core I need to do change using only one parameter**

**In Startup**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddMvc(config =>
              {
                  config.Filters.Add(new TracerAttribute());
              });

        //use our filter as a service type on the Action or Controller level
        //services.AddScoped<TracerAttribute>();

    }
```

**In ASP.NET MVC (Works Fine)**
[image: Return from Angular JS in Json]

**In ASP.NET CORE(Doesn't work)**
[image: Return from Angular JS in Json]

**Angular return for both:**

[image]

Anyone help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the angular app post json data(`Content-Type: application/json`) to .net core server side , you can get the values via `[FromBody]` :

```
[TracerAttribute]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody]Mymodel mymodel)
{

}
```

When action filter is calling , the body stream already has been read and [FromBody] model has been populated. Then you can get the data via :

```
public class TracerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        var modelValues = actionContext.ActionArguments["mymodel"] as Mymodel ;


    }
}
```